# Stack snippet is strange on Android using Google Chrome

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-snippets, mobile-web

I see strange code snippet on my OnePlus2 phone when viewing [Drawing curvy triangle in css for menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809449/drawing-curvy-triangle-in-css-for-menu/37809641#37809641)

### run button has odd look

[image]

### after I run it, snippet hides my answer

[image]

The only strange thing in my snippet is body style used, but I am not sure what is causing the problem.

Comment: It also hides the comment section on your answer - for me, anyway - but only on the mobile view.

Comment: I've reproduced it. Fix is on its way. Thanks for reporting!